# Arrays combining and separating

Tags: javascript

I have an **arrA** filled with words. Each of the words get assignet a Value starting at 1.

```
arrA = ["mango", "banana", "apple"...]
for (var i = 0; i < arrA.length; ++i)
mango = 1
banana = 2
apple= 3
```

**arrA** and **i** get implemented into a script later on which makes both values crusial for working of the programm. I want to sort arrA alphabeticly without it loosing their assigned **i**.Like this:

```
apple = 3
banana = 2
mango = 1
```

**arrA** works as a description for the user, and each **i** is used to define which scripts are going to start.
I´ve combined them with concat() and convertet them to an Array in order to sort them.

```
      var arrInput = arrA[i].split(';', 2);
      var strData = arrInput.concat(i) + '';
      var a = strData.slice(0, -2);
      var arrFruits = a.split();
      arrFruits.sort();
      
      var b = strData.slice(-2);
      value = b.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

Alerting arrFruits outputs: mango banana apple
How do I get arrA to sorting without craping up the numbers order?

Comment: you not looking into to combining (concatenate) arrays. What you need is an `object in array`

Comment: Please show _actual_ code. What you have currently shown in the first block, hardly makes any sense - it looks like you are simply assigning fixed values to individual variables named `mango`, `banana` and `apple`. No connection to your actual array to begin with, and a `for` loop that does not appear to serve any purpose in particular either.

Comment: Please dont completely change the question, if you have a new question ask a new question. Ive rolled this back to the point my answer makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` to create an object with the `value` and it's `i` number, and then use `sort` to sort by the value.

```js
const arrA = ["mango", "banana", "apple"]

const result = arrA.map( (x,i) => ({value:x, i:i+1}))
                  .sort( (a,b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't think that map is the right tool for that. An `object in array` should have been used in the first place with a logical naming of the key such as `fruit` and `index`

Comment: @tacoshy `map` is how you get that in the first place if you only have a list of strings! As per the first line of the question  _"I have an arrA filled with words"_

Comment: Yes I know and IMHO the OP should not start concatenating through `map()` but changing the architecture from start.

Comment: @tacoshy there was no concatenation when  this was first asked. Ive rolled back so this answer makes sense